# About shattering our ol' good questions with new Mma versions

Tags: discussion

I've recently seen [some good examples](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51423/193) of old questions being re-answered by using the new capabilities of v10. I think this is a good thing to happen, and we probably should encourage our community to do so.

Moreover, I would like to be able to search for all those improvements. Now and in the future (v11, ... v42). However, we all know that the local search system is lame, and without adding a (meta-) tag like [improved-v10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/improved-v10)it is almost impossible to get the desired results. As for using Google for the task, I can't think of a way to properly identify this universe.

I'd appreciate suggestions to overcome this problem.

PS: As a matter of fact, personally I don't find the current tagging system very useful and usually I query the site using only search terms. But *this one* is a tag I could use often. However I know, meta-tagging is against the rules, yep.

Comment: The bugs issue has been thoroughly dealt with [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1361/how-should-we-tag-longstanding-bugs-that-have-been-fixed). As for accepted answers I believe our ability to influence what happens is very small. As for how to identify questions that have new MMA10 answers I suggest using the API to look for questions older than xx with latest answer newer than yy. I'm hesitant to the idea of adding a tag to a question because it has a new answer. The *question* hasn't been improved. (+1 because I too have wanted to be able to identify those answers.)

Comment: I suspect this won't get anywhere, but I would be pleased if answers could be given tags, maybe only a subset of question tag set -- perhaps even limited applicable version(s).

Comment: @Pickett Removed the second part of the question (the one using the [tag:bugs] example as it was secondary and distracted from the main issue. Regarding the way to search for improvements by using dates, I don't think it will retrieve what I want.

Comment: @m_goldberg [Of course](http://teesbox.com/image/cache/data/as-seen-in-your-dreams/as-seen-in-your-dreams-868x1029.png) :D

Comment: I think a good place to start might be to take a look at all the solutions that take advantage of undocumented functionality - I think some existing solutions (for example, working with HDR images) could be updated to take advantage of functionality that has now been documented!